# Cursor position within HTMLInputElement of type date

Tags: html, date, input

I don't seem to be able to get the caret position within an `HTMLInputElement` of type date.

I try to determine this during a `keydown` event.

`HTMLInputElement` of type date does not propagate a value as long as the date is incomplete or invalid (this is how it should work according to the HTML5 standard). But I have no idea if this is also applicable to the caret position.

Methods `selectionStart` or `selectionEnd` do not reveal any information (this does work for an `HTMLInputElement` of type text).

Does anyone know how I can determine the caret position, and if I can, how this relates to the date parts year, month and day (the format is determined by the locale/language defined for the browser or platform).

Comment: Since the date-type - if supported - will show you some form of calendar widget the term "cursor position" or even "selection start/end" can only be answered in form of a date .. which is not what you would normally expect as return values from e.g. selectionStart!

Comment: You mean `caret` position. (`cursor` is the mouse pointer)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? maybe add some designs pics?

Comment: No, I'm not interested in the picker, I'm interested in the input element. I want to have some control over the input typed by the user. For example prevent the user to type beyond the fourth position of the year field. It is fine that the date input is future proof, but four positions suffice. It would also be nice if I could block the day for example, since that is fixed (01 for example).

Comment: Does the input have to be a date type input? Or do you simply wish to apply constraints to the format of the date entered in a text field?

Comment: True, that is a solution, but then I have to implement all the logic that is for free with <input type="date"..>.